# Stored Procedure throwing errors on Column Name

Tags: mysql, sql

```
delimiter $$

drop procedure if exists getEmptySeats $$
create procedure getEmptySeats(flight_number char(5),flight_date date)
begin
  select seatingID as Seats, concat(Seats.rowNumber, Seats.seatNumber) as Seat
  from Seating
  where
    aircraftID = aircraft_id and 
    seatID not in 
      ( Select seatID from Seating
        inner join Seats on Seating.seatID = Seats.seatID
        inner join Booking on Seating.bookingNumber = Booking.bookingNumber
        inner join Flights on Booking.flightCode = Flights.flightCode
        inner join FlightSchedule on Flights.flightNumber = FlightSchedule.flightNumber
        where flightNumber = flight_number and flightDate = flight_date)
order by seatingID;
end $$  

ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1

delimiter ;
```

The procedure is suppose to give a random seat in a specific airplane.
I have no idea what is wrong and I have searched the internet for so long and haven't found any thing that helped.

When I call the procedure it gives this: 
`Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Seats.rowNumber' in 'field list'`

Here is the Seats table:

```
seatID INT(11)
rowNumber TINYINT(4)
seatNumber CHAR(1)
seatPlacement VARCHAR(15)
plainID CHAR(6)
```

Comment: Can you add the structure of your `Seats` table?

Comment: And does `Seats` actually _have_ a `rowNumber` column?

Answer (score 1):

You need to join it with Seats table. The one used as a subquery can not be accessed directly

Answer (score 0):

As @Madhivanan mentioned, you need to join it with the Seats table.
There were also a few ambiguous columns which needed fixing (prefixing with the table name usually is the easiest answer unless you give the table an alias)

```
delimiter $$

drop procedure if exists getEmptySeats $$
create procedure getEmptySeats(flight_number char(5),flight_date date)
begin
    select seatingID as Seats, concat(Seats.rowNumber, Seats.seatNumber) as Seat
        from Seating
        inner join Seats on Seating.seatID = Seats.seatID
        where
            aircraftID = aircraft_id and 
            seating.seatID not in 
              ( Select seating.seatID from Seating
                inner join Seats on Seating.seatID = Seats.seatID
                inner join Booking on Seating.bookingNumber = Booking.bookingNumber
                inner join Flights on Booking.flightCode = Flights.flightCode
                inner join FlightSchedule on Flights.flightNumber = FlightSchedule.flightNumber
                where Flights.flightNumber = flight_number and flightDate = flight_date)
        order by seatingID;
end $$  

ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1

delimiter ;
```